# What's the name of the Android Privacy Settings Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-source

I can start the Android Privacy Settings Activity with the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_PRIVACY_SETTINGS);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
if(i != null) {
    getApplication().startActivity(i);
}
```

I would like to know where I can find this Activity on the Android's Source-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual `Activity` is [com.android.settings.Settings.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/settings/Settings.java).

When you pass that intent, it loads it with the `Fragment` [com.android.settings.PrivacySettings.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/settings/PrivacySettings.java)